# Переполнение стека, и GetBytes

Tags: c#

Написал код для генерации MD5 хеша:

```
public static string ToMD5(this string v)
{
    StringBuilder hashString = new StringBuilder();

    using (MD5 hash = MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] md5 = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(v));

        for (int i = 0; i < md5.Length; i++)
        {
            hashString.Append(md5[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
    }

    return hashString.ToString();
}
```

Ту есть функция GetBytes(), не будет ли в этом месте переполнение стека, если текст для хеширования будет большим

если создать byte a = new byte[99999999999], то выдаёт OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: Здесь переполнения стека не может быть, потому что вы (и ваши подфункции) не используете оператор `stackalloc`. Все объекты здесь выделяются в куче. Тут нагрузка на стек (не считая пролога) = 12 (x86) или 24 (x64) байтов.

Comment: Зачем вам MD5? если хотите создать пароль, используйте, например, BCrypt, если хотите создать просто хэш, то используйте SHA256 / SHA512.

Comment: Мне нужно записать, название ключа, SHA256 / 512 сильно длинные

Comment: Используйте SHA по-короче. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переполнения стека на будет, потому что `GetBytes()` возвращает `byte[]`, в соответственно в стеке будет только ссылка на массив, а не весь массив.

```
new byte[99999999999]
```

Вызывает не переполнение стека, а переполнение кучи.